# Is Kafka removing the relevant ACL entries automatically when deleting a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

When deleting a topic, is Kafka removing related ACL bindings automatically or do I have to manually tidy up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka does not automatically delete ACLs associated with a resource (Topic, Group, etc) when it is deleted.

If you want the ACLs to be deleted, you have to do it explicitly.